# How to connect to PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Good day, 2 weeks ago I used Mysqli and everything was ok, but now I use PDO and have many problems. It's one of them. I used next settings for connect to MySQL in MYSQLi class:

```
self::$data['host'] = 'localhost';
self::$data['user'] = 'mysql';
self::$data['pass'] = 'mysql';
self::$data['db']   = '123';
```

And it worked.
But when I used it in this:

```
private static function connect()
    {
        if(!self::$connection)
        {
            try
            {
                self::$connection = new \PDO('mysql:host='.self::$data['host'].';dbname='.self::$data['name'], self::$data['user'], self::$data['pass']);
                self::$connection -> setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$connection -> exec('SET NAMES utf8');
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                die('Ошибка подключения к БД: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

PHP call error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in PDO.

Comment: Error tells you that you have wrong login and password. Have you checked them?

Comment: You have entered wrong DB credentials.

Comment: Your db name is in `self::$data['db']`, in dsn string you use `self::$data['name']`. Are you sure?

Comment: Your connection code is wrong. Please read [how to connect properly and why you shouldn't catch](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn). With proper error reporting you would have been able to spot that silly typo yourself.

Comment: `new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);` Only a few database types support a username and password in the `$dsn` itself.

Comment: You don't need to make another class for PDO, because PDO is itself already a class. You can if you want to, but I recommend learning first how to connect to a database via PDO without making a class around it. If you are going to do this I recommend watching this series, it helped me get started with PDO https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWHkDwEoZ29Q9FKtWVjA46HC.

Answer (score 0):

```
self::$data['host'] = 'localhost';
self::$data['user'] = 'mysql';
self::$data['pass'] = 'mysql';
self::$data['db']   = '123';

private static function connect()
{
    if(!self::$connection)
    {
       try
       {
          self::$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::$data['host'].';dbname='.self::$data['db'], self::$data['user'], self::$data['pass']);
            // just correct your database name variable like as above
            self::$connection -> setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$connection -> exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            die('Ошибка подключения к БД: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is very useful